# p:dialog gets closed on validation error of a submit with ajax="false", how to keep dialog open?

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, dialog, download

I have the following `<p:dialog>`

```
<p:dialog id="dlgDownload" header="#{appmsg['header.download.popup']}" widgetVar="downloadDlg" resizable="true" modal="true" closable="true" width="640" dynamic="false">
    <h:form id="frmDownload">
        <ui:include src="downloadDialog.xhtml" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The include file contains the following download button:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnDlgDownload" value="#{appmsg['action.download.label']}" title="#{appmsg['action.download.label']}" 
    icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" ajax="false"  oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){downloadDlg.hide();} else {downloadDlg.show();}" process="@this" update=":#{p:component('pnlDownload')}" >
    <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadController.downloadFile()}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This uses `<p:fileDownload>` for downloading the file, this means I have to use `ajax="false"` for `<p:fileDownload>` to trigger.

But if there is a validation failure in the dialog, then I see that the dialog window gets closed. I want the error message to be shown in the dialog window and not in the main page.

How do I keep the dialog open, so that I can show the error message in the dialog window?

---

@Balusc Please find my attempt on SSCCE 
Basically there is a parent.xhtml where the download button resides and there is a downloadDialog.xhtml embedded on the p:dialog

```
   <p:messages id="globalMessages" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true"
        showSummary="true" closable="true" />
    <h:form = "parentForm" >
                    <p:commandButton id="btnDownload"
                        value="Download"
                        title="Download"
                 icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" onclick="downloadDlg.show();">
            </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
    <p:dialog id="dlgDownload" header="Download" widgetVar="downloadDlg" resizable="true" 
         modal="true" closable="true" width="640" dynamic="false" visible="#{frmDownload.submitted and facesContext.validationFailed}">
        <h:form id="frmDownload" binding="#{frmDownload}">
        <ui:include src="downloadDialog.xhtml" />
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Inside downloadDialog.xhtml

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

        <p:outputPanel id="pnlDownload">
    <h:panelGrid id="dateDisplayGrid" columns="4" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5" rendered="#{downloadForm.displayDates}">
    <p:calendar id="strtdt"  readonlyInput="true" size="12" value="#{downloadForm.startDate}" >
                </p:calendar>
                <h:outputText value="#{appmsg['label.to']}" />              
    <p:calendar id="enddt"  readonlyInput="true" size="12" value="#{downloadForm.endDate}"
                pattern="#{dateFormatting.shortDateFormat}" navigator="true"  >
                <f:validator validatorId="dateRangeValidator" />
                <f:attribute name="startDate" value=":#{p:component('strtdt')}" />          
                </p:calendar>
                <p:message id="dateError" for="enddt"  showDetail="true" showSummary="false"></p:message>           
            </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton id="btnDlgDownload" value="Download" title="Download" 
                     icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" ajax="false"  oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed)downloadDlg.hide();" >
    <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadController.downloadFile()}" />
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:button id="btnDlgCancel" value="#{webmsg['action.cancel']}" onclick="downloadDlg.hide(); return false" href="#" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:outputPanel>
</ui:composition>
```

When I hit the download button on the dialog window, the error gets displayed on the parent html and dialog remains closed. But when I hit the download button on parent page the dialog window reappears and contains the error message in the  inside dialog window.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What if you delegate part of the **downloadFile** method to another method?

In this case, you would need another method (let's call it **prepareDownloadFile**) that would be called using ajax. Once this method is complete you can check for errors. In case everything goes well you can call a remoteCommand (with ajax=false) to send the file to the user.

Another idea would be to use iframes. Check out this [post](http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/).

Hope that helps!