# Validation message not rendered in dialog using jsf

Tags: validation, primefaces

```
    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlgEdit" header="Add New Status">
        <h:form id="editFrm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="pnlEdit">
                <p:outputLabel value="Status"/>
                <p:inputText id="txtStatus" required="true"/>
                    <p:message for="txtStatus" />
           </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
```

This is a primefaces message tag which is not rendered in dialog.
And dialog is hide on onComplete event..

```
        How can I RENDER validation message in DIALOG using jsf?
```

Thank for any suggestion !

Comment: You need to update swapper inside dialog, you should provide the code you have tried.

Comment: You should set update="editFrm" in component that submit info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your submit button add these entries

```
ajax="true" update=":#{p:component('message')}" oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed)dlgEdit.hide();"
```

This will print your message in the same dialog.

Comment: Hey thanks man your script is very useful for me..... Thanks again for help me...byeeeeeeee

Comment: sorry man I can't vote up U B'coz I have only 11 reputation and for vote up I want minimum 15 reputation so sorry...... B'coz i'm new in stackoverflow and please tell me how to gain reputation.....

Comment: Thanks man i used that script but sorry man i have to set ajax="false" so this is not work give me another example and thanks it is working if ajax="true" so don't mind but my requirement is work only in ajax="false". so please give me another example with ajax="false" and thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok if your validation message is displayed in the parent page?

If yes, in that case you can throw a feedback error message. This will be picked up by the p:message in your parent page.

If no, please refer to this question below in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150728/pdialog-gets-closed-on-validation-error-of-a-submit-with-ajax-false-how-to-k) for dialog window with ajax=false situation.